# how to check multiple buttons click and save the value in database?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have 6 `UIButtons` in custom cell named as follows:

```
btnR
btnCos
btnIn
btnOut
btnNA
btnNO
```

Can I click on any button and more than one button same time and get those values in database?
How can I store these values and save on `NSMutableArray`?
Please can anyone help me.

Comment: Just add different tags on your button and save values accordingly

Comment: use [button tag] property of the button to check which button is tapped and add to nsmutablearray

Comment: @suhit: I have done that already,but i cant save the tag value in the local database.

Comment: @suhit:I want some help in code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a view ignores all but the first touch during a multitouch sequence. If you want the view to handle multiple touches, you must enable this capability for the view by setting the related attribute in Interface Builder under View -> Interaction ->check `Multiple Touch` or by programmatically setting the `multipleTouchEnabled` property of your view to YES.

If you want to use same method on click you can set tags to buttons and save whatever data you want in database upon receiving event.

Comment: :only my last button click is saving in the database. But i want to save multiple button clicks. Can you please help me out.